# How can I set common cmake flags for all my packages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to setup cxx compiler flags common for all my packages, but I can't edit CMakeLists.txt in my catkin workspace folder. I can edit only separate catkin packages CMakeLists.txt. What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220532/how-can-i-set-common-cmake-flags-for-all-my-packages?/) by [msporyshev](https://answers.ros.org/users/25017/msporyshev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass cmake options to catkin_make, e.g., `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1